# Change color by mouse over

Tags: javascript

I'ld like to change the "`imgTag.style.border='5px solid #FF00FF'`" to black when the mouse is over an image.
This is my JavaScript:

```
javascript:for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;i++)  
     {
     var imgTag=document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i];   
     imgTag.style.border='5px solid #FF00FF';
     imgTag.title=''; 
     imgTag.onclick=function()
          { 
         return !window.open('http://www.example.com/#/'+this.src);
          }
      }
    void(0)
```

How can it be done?
Thanks
Frank

Comment: CSS as suggested by Thomas is the cleanest solution. As an aside, if you want to use an image for navigation you should wrap it in an `<a>` element (and do the navigation from the `<a>`) so that it will be accessible to keyboard users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind handlers to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to change the image's border color:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i) {
    imgs[i].onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.borderColor = '#000';
    };
    imgs[i].onmouseout = function() {
        this.style.borderColor = '#f0f';
    };
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/bNk4Y/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong with the code you have, but if i understand your question correctly, this should do it:
HTML:

```
<img src="" >
<img src="">
...
```

JS:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++)
{
    imgs[i].onmouseover = function() {this.style.border="1px red solid";};   
}
```

Note, however, that this can easily be achieved with CSS as well, which is a better practice - in case users have JS disabled, etc

```
img:hover {
border: 1px red solid;
}
```