# Javascript: Highlight all paragraphs when the mouse moves over them and then revert back once the mouse has passed

Tags: javascript, highlight, mouseover

I am completely new to Javascript; please could someone assist me with my question in the simplest way possible for me to understand.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+hover+paragraph+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Possibly no need for JavaScript. Look up css hover paragraph

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color by mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171562/change-color-by-mouse-over)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with CSS or Javascript. Either way, the result is the same.

### CSS

You can do this by wrapping the paragraphs in a `<div>`, and then making a CSS `:hover` selector.

```css
.paragraphs:hover {
  color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraphs">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
</div>
```

### JS

Wrap all the paragraphs in a `<div>`, then add an [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) event listener.

```js
var paragraphs = document.querySelector('.paragraphs');

paragraphs.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  paragraphs.style.color = 'lightgreen';
});

paragraphs.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  paragraphs.style.color = 'black';
});
```

```html
<div class="paragraphs">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this solved your problem, hit the checkmark above to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't need JS for that. You can simply use a CSS Selector like **hover** to add some effects on the HTML element when you hover them.

```
a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thank, however i am doing an online bootcamp and i have to use javascript but i will keep this in mind for future coding

Answer (score 0):

You can use addEventListner and listen for scroll over. In the callback you can toggle the class.

Comment: if you can provide the sample code then it would be easier to understand.